# Swift equal function dont work

Tags: swift, equals, func

i want to check equality between objects but i get an error. Error is within the code.

```
class Test {
    var key: String

    init(nameParam: String) {
        self.key = nameParam
    }


    func ==(other: Test) -> Bool {
        return other.key == self.key
    }

}

var t1 = Test(nameParam: "Test")
var t2 = Test(nameParam: "Test1")

if(t1 == t2) { // Error: 'Test' is not convertible to 'MirrorDisposition'
    println("...")
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Swift Equatable Protocol](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24467960/swift-equatable-protocol)

Answer (score 3):

Operators must be implemented in the global scope, not inside the class. So you should implement your equality operator outside of the class:

```
class Test {...}

func == (lhs: Test, rhs: Test) -> Bool {
    return lhs.key == rhs.key
}
```

Suggested reading: [Operator Functions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/AdvancedOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH27-XID_79)

Answer (score 1):

You should write it like that:

```
class Test : Equatable {
    var key: String

    init(nameParam: String) {
        self.key = nameParam
    }




}

func ==(lhs:Test,rhs: Test) -> Bool {
    return lhs.key == rhs.key
}

var t1 = Test(nameParam: "Test")
var t2 = Test(nameParam: "Test1")

if(t1 == t2) {
    println("...")
}
```