# Redundant conformance of 'Generic' to protocol 'Equatable' in Swift 2.2

Tags: swift, protocols, equatable

I am Having an error in Equatable while compilation.
I wanted to add find or contains method in the list to check the value.
**My Code Below**

```
class Generic: NSObject, Equatable, NSCoding //Am Having an error -  Redundant conformance of 'Generic' to protocol 'Equatable'

{

  var genericCode: String?
  var genericName : String?
  var genericType : String?
  var genericImageUrl : String?
  var genericPhone: String?
  var orgName : String?

override init()
{

    self.genericCode = String("")
    self.genericName = String("")
    self.genericType = String("")
    self.genericImageUrl = String("")
    self.genericPhone = String("")
    self.orgName = String("")

}

//Parameterzed Constructor for the Generic
init(genericCode: String , genericName: String , genericPhone: String, genericType: String, genericImageUrl : String)
{
    self.genericCode = genericCode
    self.genericName = genericName
    self.genericType = genericType
    self.genericImageUrl = genericImageUrl
    self.genericPhone = genericPhone

}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    genericCode = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("genericCode") as? String
    genericName = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("genericName") as? String
    genericType = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("genericType") as? String
    genericPhone = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("genericPhone") as? String
}

func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
    aCoder.encodeObject(genericCode, forKey: "genericCode")
    aCoder.encodeObject(genericName, forKey: "genericName")
    aCoder.encodeObject(genericType, forKey: "genericType")
    aCoder.encodeObject(genericPhone, forKey: "genericPhone")
}
```

}

```
func ==(lhs: Generic, rhs: Generic) -> Bool
{
  return lhs.genericCode == rhs.genericCode
}
```

Error has occured , Is it because i am using NSCoding and NSobject?

Comment: `NSObject` is already `Equatable` in Swift2, so you can remove the protocol declaration: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34515270/14955

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSObject), `NSObject` conforms to `Equatable`:

> **Conforms To**
>  
>   CVarArgType
>   CustomDebugStringConvertible
>  
>   CustomStringConvertible
>  
>   Equatable
>  
>   Hashable
>  
>   NSObjectProtocol

... therefore, like your error says, conformance to Equatable is redundant...

Comment: Have removed the error but not checking with Contains method?  Doing code like below  ....     if !readArray.contains(generic)
           {
                readArray.append(generic)
            }  Am i doing something wronge here?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37391580/swift-2-2-contains-method-not-working  ... Have added another call

Answer (score 31):

A class inheriting `NSObject` already conforms to `Equatable`. So declaring `Object: Equatable` is redundant.

However, the conformance does not mean that it has been implemented properly (`NSObject` just checks whether the pointers are the same). If you wish to properly implement `Equatable` for `NSObject`, just exclude the protocol conformance statement (`: Equatable`), but still implement the comparison method:

```
static func ==(lhs: Object, rhs: Object) -> Bool {
   return lhs.text == rhs.text
}
```

Comment: Can I override `isEqual()` instead of the `static func ==` and still use == to compare?

Comment: @Eddie yes, tested it in a Playground