# Swift 2.2, Contains Method not working

Tags: swift, contains, equatable

Contains method not working properly and it is giving me false result even if it is matching with Object?

**My Code Below**

```
class Generic: NSObject, NSCoding
{

  var genericCode: String?
  var genericName : String?
  var genericType : String?
  var genericImageUrl : String?
  var genericPhone: String?
  var orgName : String?

  override init()
  {

    self.genericCode = String("")
    self.genericName = String("")
    self.genericType = String("")
    self.genericImageUrl = String("")
    self.genericPhone = String("")
    self.orgName = String("")

  }

  //Parameterzed Constructor for the Generic
  init(genericCode: String , genericName: String , genericPhone: String, genericType: String, genericImageUrl : String)
  {
    self.genericCode = genericCode
    self.genericName = genericName
    self.genericType = genericType
    self.genericImageUrl = genericImageUrl
    self.genericPhone = genericPhone

  }

  required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    genericCode = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("genericCode") as? String
    genericName = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("genericName") as? String
    genericType = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("genericType") as? String
    genericPhone = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey("genericPhone") as? String
  }

  func encodeWithCoder(aCoder: NSCoder) {
    aCoder.encodeObject(genericCode, forKey: "genericCode")
    aCoder.encodeObject(genericName, forKey: "genericName")
    aCoder.encodeObject(genericType, forKey: "genericType")
    aCoder.encodeObject(genericPhone, forKey: "genericPhone")
  }
}

func ==(lhs: Generic, rhs: Generic) -> Bool
{
  return lhs.genericCode == rhs.genericCode
}
```

**Checking in ViewController**

```
print(readArray.contains(generic))
if !readArray.contains(generic)
{
            readArray.append(generic)
}
```

Comment: Your class inherits from `NSObject` – you therefore need to override `isEqual` to do comparisons.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bug with equals operator and NSObjects in Swift 2.0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31099379/bug-with-equals-operator-and-nsobjects-in-swift-2-0)

Comment: `String("")` and just `""` is exactly the same and be aware of using optional properties and a non-optional initializer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**OPTION 1**

The reason is that your class is inheriting from `NSObject`, therefore, you must fulfill the `NSObjectProtocol` instead of `Equatable`:

```
override func isEqual(object: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
     if let object = object as? Generic {
         return self.genericCode == object.genericCode
     }
     return false
 }
```

**OPTION 2**

Inherit from `Equatable` instead of `NSObject` (you probably can't use this option, since you seem to need `NSCoding`)

*Note that with newer versions of Swift you probably should use
**OPTION 3:** Use `Codable` instead of `NSCodable`*

Comment: That's just `isEqual` comparing the pointers – if you try to compare two different instances with the same `genericCode`, it won't work (try putting a breakpoint in the `==` overload, it'll never get tripped).

Comment: XCode 10.1: `override func isEqual(_ object: Any?) -> Bool`