# Check if an object is the last in the array

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, macos, cocoa-touch

I have an array of `[myObject]` called `myArray` and an `myObject` object.

I want to check if `myObject` is the last object in `myArray`.

What is the best way to do it?

I've tried:

```
if myObject == myArray.last!
```

but it gives me this error:

```
Binary operator '==' cannot be applied to two 'myObject' operands
```

Any idea?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried "isEqualTo:"? Have you debugged that both the object are of same type/class?

Comment: What type your object is? Does it conform to `Equatable`?

Comment: Your object has to conform to Equatable. I have an example here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32953118/2227743

Comment: @fiks what is `Equatable`?

Comment: @EricD what is `Equatable`?

Comment: what is your value that u save in your array describe here

Comment: if you need to compare custom objects then those should conform to equatable protocal. Please see http://nshipster.com/swift-comparison-protocols/

Comment: Try the operator === This operator compare reference in memory

Comment: You need your `myObject` class to implement the `Equatable` protocol. Also the class name should be `MyObject`

Comment: question is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24467960/swift-equatable-protocol

Comment: Please study the answer in the duplicate link. There's also other examples on SO, of course, if you still struggle with the concept. You should also read the Swift manual, where protocols are explained.

Answer (score -1):

Try this one may be work for you.

```
let ary = ["1","2","3"]

if ary[0].isEqual(ary.last!){
    print("Is last object")
}else{
    print("Is Not last object")
}
```

**Your output should be:Is Not last object**

```
let ary = ["1"]

if ary[0].isEqual(ary.last!){
    print("Is last object")
}else{
    print("Is Not last object")
}
```

**Your output should be:Is last object**

Comment: OP has an array of *objects* (class or struct instances for example), not an array of strings.

Comment: Here you can try compare any type of object.

Comment: No. It doesn't work for class/structs instances if they do not conform to Equatable. You should read the link I've given to OP...